# GAE: Error when downloading data, if ndb.KeyProperty(repeated=True)

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am creating the bulkloader.yaml automatically from my existing schema and have trouble downloading my data due the `repeated=True` of my KeyProperty.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    firstname = ndb.StringProperty()
    friends = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User', repeated=True)
```

The automatic created bulkloader looks like this:

```
- kind: User
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    # TODO: Add connector options here--these are specific to each connector.
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

    - property: firstname
      external_name: firstname
      # Type: String Stats: 2 properties of this type in this kind.

    - property: friends
      external_name: friends
      # Type: Key Stats: 2 properties of this type in this kind.
      import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('User')
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
google.appengine.ext.bulkload.bulkloader_errors.ErrorOnTransform: Error on transform. Property: friends External Name: friends. Code: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string Details: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_path'
```

What can I do please?

**Possible Solution:**

After Tony's tip I came up with this:

```
- property: friends
      external_name: friends
      # Type: Key Stats: 2 properties of this type in this kind.
      import_transform: myfriends.stringToValue(';') 
      export_transform: myfriends.valueToString(';')
```

**myfriends.py**

```
def valueToString(delimiter):
    def key_list_to_string(value):
        keyStringList = []
        if value == '' or value is None or value == []:
            return None 
        for val in value:                
            keyStringList.append(transform.key_id_or_name_as_string(val))        
        return delimiter.join(keyStringList)
    return key_list_to_string
```

And this works! The encoding is in Unicode though: UTF-8. Make sure to open the file in LibreOffice as such or you would see garbled content.

The biggest challenge is import.  This is what I came up with without any luck:

```
def stringToValue(delimiter):    
    def string_to_key_list(value):
        keyvalueList = []
        if value == '' or value is None or value == []:
            return None        
        for val in value.split(';'):            
            keyvalueList.append(transform.create_foreign_key('User'))        
        return keyvalueList
    return string_to_key_list
```

I get the error message:

```
BadValueError: Unsupported type for property friends: <type 'function'>
```

According to Datastore viewer, I need to create something like this:

```
[datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'User', u'kave@gmail.com', _app=u's~myapp1')]
```

**Update 2:**

Tony you are to be a real expert in Bulkloader. Thanks for your help.  Your solution worked!
I have moved my other question to a new thread.

But one crucial problem that appears is that, when I create new users I can see my `friends` field shown as `<missing>` and it works fine.

Now when I use your solution to upload the data, I see for those users without any friend entries a `<null>` entry.  Unfortunately this seems to break the model since friends can't be null.

Changing the model to reflect this, seems to be ignored.

```
friends = ndb.KeyProperty(kind='User', repeated=True, required=False)
```

How can I fix this please?

**update:**

digging further into it:
when the status `<missing>` is shown in the data viewer, in code it shows `friends = []`
However when I upload the data via csv I get a `<null>`, which translates to `friends = [None]`. I know this, because I exported the data into my local data storage and could follow it in code.  Strangely enough if I empty the list `del user.friends[:]`, it works as expected.  There must be a beter way to set it while uploading via csv though...

**Final Solution**

This turns out to be a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3646) that hasn't been resolved since over one year.

In a nutshell, even though there is no value in csv, because a list is expected, gae makes a list with a None inside.  This is game breaking, since retrieval of such a model ends up in an instant crash.

Adding a `post_import_function`, which deletes the lists with a None inside.

In my case:

```
def post_import(input_dict, instance, bulkload_state_copy):
    if instance["friends"] is None:
        del instance["friends"]
    return instance
```

Finally everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using repeated properties and exporting to a CSV, you should be doing some formatting to concatenate the list into a CSV understood format. Please check the example here on [import/export of list of dates](http://longsystemit.com/javablog/?p=23) and hope it can help you.

**EDIT** :  Adding suggestion for import transform from an earlier comment to this answer

For import, please try something like:

```
 `from google.appengine.api import datastore 
    def stringToValue(delimiter): 
        def string_to_key_list(value): 
            keyvalueList = [] 
            if value == '' or value is None or value == []: return None 
            for val in value.split(';'): 
                keyvalueList.append(datastore.Key.from_path('User', val)) 
            return keyvalueList 
        return string_to_key_list`
```

if you have id instead of name , add like val = int(val)

Comment: Tony, thank you so much for your help. I have managed to finish the Export and it works. But the import is in my case very difficult. Any idea how I could do that? Please see updated question.

Comment: For import, please try something like:

`from google.appengine.api import datastore
def stringToValue(delimiter):    
    def string_to_key_list(value):
        keyvalueList = []
        if value == '' or value is None or value == []:
            return None        
        for val in value.split(';'):            
            keyvalueList.append(datastore.Key.from_path('User', val))        
        return keyvalueList
    return string_to_key_list`

if you have id instead of name , add like val = int(val)

Comment: Tony, if you put your import suggestion in your main answer you can format it properly. :-)

Comment: @GuidovanRossum , i have moved the code suggestion to my answer for proper formatting. Can you please see if the code logic is correct.

Comment: @tony, thank you so much for your help on this. Yes it seems to have worked. But there is a related problem, which I have explained in the updated question. GAE assigns very high id's, which become a problem upon re-uploading.

Comment: ok, the big ids seems to be due to the new scattered ids feature in app engine. let's try to figure out. i suggest that we move the newest id related issue to a separate thread. this current question has a title related to repeated property and so let us keep it related to import and export of repeated properties for the sake of reference of future users with same issue. if you put a new question on handling ids in bulkupload, more people may also join the conversation and will be good for future use of others who may face the same id related issue.

Comment: @tony, I broke down the problem with `<missing>` and `<null>`. Please see updated question, maybe you have an idea?  And I moved the big id question to a new thread as you suggested. many thanks

Comment: @Kave , you will see <missing> only in datastore viewer . this happens when you update your model schema by adding a new property and then existing entities will not be having anything for this property and datastore viewer shows them as <missing>. when you update these entities for the property,<missing> will go. getting none is expected when you create/update an entity without a value for a property. the current import transform returns None when no value is present in csv. is the None affecting your application logic?

Comment: @tony, i have found the solution. It is a bug in gae, which is unfixed since over a year. There is a workaround, which I have explained in my question. Thanks